# The fundamental group of a compact, locally simply connected space is finitely generated

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a compact space that is also locally simply connected (any point has a local base of simply connected open sets). Prove that the fundamental group at any point is finitely generated.

Comment: Start with: There is a finite cover of $X$ by simply-connected open subsets of $X$.

Comment: How to solve the case when two of this sets have intersection with infinitely many connected components?

Comment: Can a space with infinitely many connected components be compact?

Comment: Yes, for example the Cantor set.

Comment: Sorry, I rewrite my comment more clearly: "How to solve the case when the intersection of two of these sets has infinitely many connected components? "

Comment: Note: it is not enough to just assume that $X$ is a finite union of simply connected sets. For example, let $S=\{0\}\cup\{1/n\colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $X=(S\times[0,1])\cup([0,1]\times\{0,1\})$. This is a kind of comb space, and union of two open simply connected (and contractible) subsets. Yet, its fundamental group is the free group on a countably infinite generating set.

Comment: @user136725 do you need the result in this full generality? If you had e.g. local path-connectedness you could try to imitate the proof that compact Riemannian manifolds have f.g. fundamental groups. (See for example Gromov - Metric structures of..., p.90 Prop 3.22)

Comment: @GeorgeLowther your space may be compact but it is not locally simply connected. So I think you are wrong with your note.

Comment: @Dan: I never claimed that my example was locally simply connected. Just, that it has a cover consisting of simply connected sets and does not have finitely generated fundamental group. For example, it looks to me that WMycroft's argument would apply to this space, so can't be correct.

Comment: @Dan: It does admit such covers. e.g., $\{X\setminus([0,1]\times\{0\}),X\setminus([0,1]\times\{1\})\}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a proof that the fundamental group is finitely generated. The properties required of the space $X$ which I will require are that it is a compact (Hausdorff) space, has a cover by open simply connected sets, and which is locally path connected (i.e., there is a base for the topology consisting of path connected sets). As, by definition, a simply connected set is also path connected, the conditions are met for any compact locally simply connected space.

> **Lemma**: Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover for a compact space $X$. Then, there exists an open cover $\mathcal{V}$ such that, for all $V_1,V_2\in\mathcal{V}$ with $V_1\cap V_2\not=\emptyset$, there exists a $U\in\mathcal{U}$ with $V_1\cup V_2\subseteq U$.

I'll prove this in a moment, but first show that it implies that $X$ has finitely generated fundamental group. By the assumptions on $X$, we can let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover consisting of simply connected sets. Then, let $\mathcal{V}$ be as in the lemma. By breaking each element of $\mathcal{V}$ into its connected components (which will also be path connected, by local path connectedness of $X$), we can assume that each $V\in\mathcal{V}$ is path connected and non-empty. Also, by compactness of $X$, we can assume that $\mathcal{V}$ is a finite cover. Say, $\mathcal{V}=\{V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_n\}$.

Let $I=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and, for each $i\in I$, choose a point $P_i\in V_i$. Also, define $J\subseteq I\times I$ to be the pairs $(i,j)$ such that $V_i\cap V_j\not=\emptyset$. As $V_i\cup V_j$ is path connected, we can find continuous $\gamma_{i,j}\colon[0,1]\to V_i\cup V_j$ with $\gamma_{ij}(0)=P_i$ and $\gamma_{ij}(1)=P_j$.
Note that the path $\gamma_{ij}$ is unique up to homotopy. If $f\colon[0,1]\to V_i\cap V_j$ was any other path with $f(0)=P_i$ and $f(1)=P_j$ then, by the properties of $\mathcal{V}$ given in the lemma, there is a $U\in\mathcal{U}$ containing $V_i\cup V_j$ and, hence, containing the paths of $\gamma_{ij}$ and $f$. By simple connectedness of $U$, $f$ must be homotopic to $\gamma_{ij}$.

Now, consider any path $f\colon[0,1]\to X$ with $f(0),f(1)$ in $\{P_1,\ldots,P_n\}$. As $\{f^{-1}(V_i)\colon i\in I\}$ covers the unit interval, there exists $0=t_0\le t_1\le\cdots\le t_m=1$ such that each interval $[t_{k-1},t_k]$ is contained in one of the $f^{-1}(V_k)$, say, $V_{i_k}$. we can define $i_0$ such that $f(0)=P_{i_0}$ and, wlog, choose $i_m$ such that $f(1)=P_{i_m}$.

As $f(t_{k-1})\in V_{i_{k-1}}\cap V_{i_k}$ for each $k$, we see that $(i_{k-1},i_k)\in J$. We can define a path $f_k$ joining $P_{i_{k-1}}$ to $P_{i_k}$ by first taking a path joining $P_{k-1}$ to $f(t_{k-1})$, then take $f$ restricted to $[t_{k-1},t_k]$, then join $f(t_k)$ to $P_{i_k}$ along a path in $V_{i_k}$. Joining these paths together, $f_1 * f_2 * \cdots * f_m$, we get back to $f$ (up to homotopy equivalence). Then, as noted above, each $f_k$ must be homotopic to $\gamma_{i_{k-1}i_k}$. So, we have the homotopy equivalence,
$$
f\cong\gamma_{i_0i_1}*\gamma_{i_1i_2}*\cdots *\gamma_{i_{m-1}i_m}.
$$
Now let $\tilde I$ be the set of $i\in I$ such that $P_i$ is in the same path connected component of $X$ as $P$, and $\tilde J=J\cap (\tilde I\times\tilde I)$. For each $i\in\tilde I$, let $\gamma_i$ be a path jointing $P$ to $P_i$ and, for each $(i,j)\in\tilde J$, let $\tilde\gamma_{ij}=\gamma_i*\gamma_{ij}*\gamma_j^{-1}$ (here, I have used $\gamma^{-1}_j$ to denote the path $\gamma_j$ run backwards). Then, $\tilde\gamma_{ij}$ are paths joining $P$ to itself, and
$$
f\cong\tilde\gamma_{i_0i_1}*\tilde\gamma_{i_1i_2}*\cdots *\tilde\gamma_{i_{m-1}i_m}.
$$
So, the equivalence classes $[\tilde\gamma_{ij}]$ for $(i,j)\in\tilde J$ is a finite generating set for the fundamental group of $X$ at $P$.

---

Proof of lemma:

Note, that if $X$ was a metric space then [Lebesgue's number lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma) implies that for some $r > 0$, every open ball of radius $r$ is contained in a member of $\mathcal{U}$, and we can take $\mathcal{V}$ to be the collection of open balls of radius $r/2$. For non-metrizable spaces we need to do a bit more work. Actually, it can be shown that every open cover has an open [star-refinement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_refinement) (this is a consequence of [compact ⇒ paracompact ⇒ fully normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Paracompact_space&oldid=635134805#Variations)), which is a stronger version of the lemma, although we don't need that here.

First, as the space $X$ is compact, we can restrict $\mathcal{U}$ to be a finite open cover. Say, $\mathcal{U}=\{U_1,U_2,\ldots,U_n\}$. I'll prove the result by induction on $n$. The case with $n=1$ is clear, as we can take $\mathcal{V}=\mathcal{U}=\{X\}$.

Now, suppose that $n > 1$. Taking $\tilde U_2=U_2\cup\cdots\cup U_n$, we have $U_1\cup\tilde U_2=X$. So, $X\setminus U_1$ is a closed subset of $\tilde U_2$. As compact spaces are normal, we can find open sets $W_1,W_2$ with,
$$
X\setminus U_1\subseteq W_1\subseteq\bar W_1\subseteq W_2\subseteq\bar W_2\subseteq\tilde U_2.
$$
As $\{U_2,\ldots,U_n\}$ covers $\bar W_2$, the induction hypothesis gives an open cover $\mathcal{V}_0$ for $\bar W_2$ (with the subspace topology) such that, if $V_1,V_2\in\mathcal{V}_0$ have nonempty intersection then $V_1\cup V_2\subseteq U$ for some $U\in\mathcal{U}$.

Let us now set,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{V}_1&=\left\{V\cap W_1\colon V\in\mathcal{V}_0\right\},\\
\mathcal{V}_2&=\left\{V\cap W_2\cap U_1\colon V\in\mathcal{V}_0\right\}.
\end{align}
These are collections of open sets in the topology of $X$ and, for any $V_1,V_2\in\mathcal{V}_1\cup\mathcal{V}_2$ with nonempty intersection, then $V_1\cup V_2\subseteq U$ for some $U\in\mathcal{U}$. They cover $W_1\cup(W_2\cap U_1)$, which is equal to $W_2$.
Furthermore, all elements of $\mathcal{V}_1$ are disjoint from $X\setminus\bar W_1\subseteq U_1$ and all elements of $\mathcal{V}_2$ are contained in $U_1$. Then,
$$
\mathcal{V}=\mathcal{V}_1\cup\mathcal{V}_2\cup\{X\setminus \bar W_1\}
$$
satisfies the requirements of the lemma.

Comment: nice proof...   :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this question interesting, here's my attempt at a solution, it should probably be checked as I'm not 100% certain...

Fix some basepoint $z \in X$

At each point $x \in X$, let $U_x$ be a simply connected open neighbourhood of $x$. The $U_x$ form an open cover so since $X$ is compact we can take a finite subcover $U_{x_1}, \dots, U_{x_n}$, where WLOG $z \in U_{x_1}$.

Now consider a path $f \colon I \to X$ based at $z$. The path $f$ passes through the $U_{x_i}$ in some order, beginning and terminating in $U_{x_1}$. This yields a finite sequence $S_f = (v_1, v_2, \dots, v_m)$ where $v_1 = v_m = x_1$. Note since each $U_{x_i}$ is simply connected, any two paths $f_1, f_2$ with $S_{f_1} = S_{f_2}$ are homotopic.

For each finite sequence, $S$ of length less than $2n$ such that if there exists a path $f$ with $S_f = S$ pick such an $f$ and let $G$ be the set of all such $f$'s. This is a finite set, and I claim it generates $\pi_1(X; z)$.

Let $f$ be any path in $X$ based at $z$ and consider $S_f$. If this has length less than $2n$ then $f$ is homotopic to an element of $G$ and so we are done. Otherwise we can pick minimal $i<j$ such that $v_i = v_j$. Then $f$ is homotopic to the composition of two loops $g$ and $f'$ where $S_g = (v_1, \dots, v_j, v_{i-1}, \dots, v_1)$ and $S_{f'} = (v_1, ... v_{i-1}, v_j, \dots v_n)$. Now $g \in G$ and $S_{f'}$ is shorter than $S_f$ so we can repeat this process until we express $f$ as the composition of elements in $G$.

Sorry, I was a bit rushed writing up the final section, let me know if anything is unclear and I can elaborate.

Comment: I really like the idea, but I'm afraid the map $f\mapsto S_f$ is not well defined. As soon as you leave one of the opens you might end up in the intersection of two other of the covering sets and hence there's no unique way to define the next member of the sequence. Is there an obvious equivalence relation we can put on the set of sequences to fix this?

Comment: Does it really matter? If we land in the intersection we can always assume we land in the one with the smallest index. But I agree that should be mentioned!

Comment: However now that I think about it, I worry that $S_f$ may not necessarily be finite?

Comment: I am not sure with the fact that $S_{f_1} = S_{f_2}$ implies $f_1 and f_2$ are homotopic...for an example consider $X=S^1$ and $U_1= S^1-1 U_2=S^1- {-1}$ ...then for two loops  $a$ and $a^{-1}$ $S_a = S_{a^{-1}}$ ...I might be wrong...just tell me this

Comment: I agree with AnubhaV, the fact that Sf1=Sf2 doesn't imply that f1 and f2 are homotopic.

Comment: Woops, I appear to have missed that - good spot. However, I believe we should be able to work around this hitch, since these problems are just caused by inverses, which we would obtain for free from a generating set. I'll see if I can formalise this when I get the chance...